# How to make basic ember setup in jsFiddle

Tags: ember.js, jsfiddle

I'm trying to test my ember code in my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/synthresin/KBANX/)

I set framework to `Ember 1.0.0-rc1` and `onDomReady`

and I added jQuery as a resource.

and I setup basic application template in html and declare application in js.

I think I set very basic of an ember app. but it doesn't work.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an up to date fiddle/jsbin link in the Ember Contributing document:

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

It is always up to date with the master version of ember.

Comment: The jsbin gets updated, the fiddle does not. I've filed a bug ;) The jsbin also has a permalink: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/

Answer (score 2):

Two things are going wrong here.

1. There is a bug in the way jsFiddle has implemented ember support. First off it should be including jQuery, and also it is loading ember before handlebars. You can see what's going on by right-clicking on the output frame and selecting view-source. As a workaround, manually add references to these libraries.
2. You've got a typo. Instead of `type="type/handlebars"` you should specify `type="text/handlebars"`

Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zHWje/)

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely use [emberjs.jsbin.com](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/).  It has everything already setup.